# Wired connection fails to upload files to Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, upload, windows-10, wired

Here's the situation.

I have an EC2 Ubuntu instance (henceforth called the server) running a few websites.

I have a home network of two computers:

- The desktop PC is connected to the router (via a wired connection).
- The laptop is connected wirelessly to the same router.

Both computers run Windows 10.

I'm trying to upload an image (a .jpg photo) from the desktop PC to a website on the server (via the web interface). It starts uploading for a few seconds then stops and never completes the upload.

However, I can upload the same file from the laptop (which is presumably in the same network as the desktop PC) without any issue.

If I try to upload that file via FTP from the desktop PC, the transfer times out.

But from the desktop PC, I can upload that same photo to Facebook or other website without any problem, so I guess it's a combination of this specific machine with this specific server that's having an issue, though I am completely clueless as to where I should investigate to solve the problem

(Note that transfers from the desktop PC to the server used to be fine, but I can't really tell what's changed since it stopped working)

Any lead for where I should look?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you open a terminal and run `tracert <ec2 IP address>` from your wired and wireless connections, and post the output here?

Comment: Output from the desktop PC:

http://pastebin.com/xq7NL3MQ

Comment: Output from the laptop http://pastebin.com/RV6CW5pa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating the network drivers, the transfers didn't time out any more but were very slow.

Then I disabled the IPv4 Checksum Offload and now everything is back to normal.